# oocss-compass plugin setup

Tags: sass, compass-sass, oocss

I'm having trouble in the setup of oocss-compass plugin.
The steps I did:

1. Downloaded the oocss-compass and placed it on my desktop (https://github.com/he8us/oocss-compass)
   Inside the oocss-compass destkop folder I runed:

   ```
   rvm use @global
   gem build oocss-compass.gemspec
   gem install oocss-compass-[GEMVERSION].gem
   ```

   The gem is on my gem list (oocss-compass)
2. Then on my working folder (not RoR project, just empty folders and html static pages), I runed:

   ```
   compass create css -r oocss-compass --using oocss-compass
   ```

And it returns me an error:

```
Errno::ENOENT on line ["95"] of /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/compass-0.11.7/lib/compass/installers/base.rb: No such file or directory - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/oocss-compass-0.0.1/lib/../templates/project/partials/_base.sass
```

What can be missing or what i did wrong on the installation?

Comment: I would ask this question to the github repo owner directly. Might however be related to your RVM setup, what is your intention with `@global`?

Comment: Well with global i can access from other gemsets. But in this case was just for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I've just submitted the modifications to GitHub and published a gem on Rubygems.org ;)

You can update the gem and start building...

Have a nice day,
He8us

Answer (score 0):

I'm the owner of the repository.

I've just did the test and I have the same problem. It's probably because Compass changed the way to create the plugins. I will look at it and come back to you asap.