# compass-bootstrap on a non RoR/Ruby project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, compass-sass

I was looking into the following two bootstrap plugins for compass:

https://github.com/vwall/compass-twitter-bootstrap

https://github.com/hecbuma/compass-bootstrap

Is it possible to setup one of this two compass plugins on a non RoR/Ruby project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, for both of them. Make sure to install the gems and import them as described to your scss- or sass-files.

When you run `compass watch` or `compass compile` in your project folder it will compile your code as usual.

Comment: Yes, it works. I guess I just got confused in the warnings of the missing icons :) Thank you.

Comment: Btw, do you know anything of oocss-compass ?
I have this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/9428881/1230471