# Is Compass compatible with Twitter Bootstrap? (without special packages and pain?)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, compass-sass

Does Twitter Bootstrap "play well" with Compass?  It seems like the best of both words for my non-Ruby on Rails project.

I found two posts but I don't understand them: [compass-vs-twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127677/compass-vs-twitter-bootstrap) and [compass-bootstrap-on-a-non-ror-ruby-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429207/compass-bootstrap-on-a-non-ror-ruby-project).

They mention a special build [compass-twitter-bootstrap](https://github.com/vwall/compass-twitter-bootstrap) but I worry it will fall out of sync on one or both fronts.

I'd rather just install them both "as-is."  Just wondering if anyone has had experience and can give insight and/or tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compass is a library built on top of Sass, Bootstrap was a Less project, but now they have a Sass version of Bootstrap.

I strongly recommend that you use the Sass version with Compass, that way you can write additional CSS on top of your Bootstrap using Compass mixins, and rewrite the native styles that don't fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an official version of Bootstrap-Sass (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass). 
 
Compass is compatible with Bootstrap and have some nice features such as spriting, mixins for lists and css3. You can copy /vendor/assets where you want and just compile these styles by compass (compass --watch)